# How to point domain name to Amazon EC2 subdirectory

Tags: linux, networking, dns, amazon-ec2

I'm having trouble pointing a domain name to a subdirectory on an Amazon EC2 instance.

**FYI - I'm not too experienced with DNS or networking ...**

So jumping right in ...

- I set up an Amazon EC2 instance with an elastic IP, for example, "*1.2.3.4*"
- Edit: Apache2 server is installed on the instance.
- I put a site under a folder, for example, "*/var/www/html/website*"
- I have a domain name, for example, "*example.com*"
- I've set up Route 53 with a hosted zone "*example.com*" with an A record that points to "*1.2.3.4*"

So when I go to "*example.com*", I get the Amazon Test Page.

How would I get "*example.com*" to point to the "*/var/www/html/website*" folder

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: One thing I forgot to mention is that I have other folders for different websites that I want different domain names to point too. Eg. "*example.com*" points to "*/var/www/html/website1*" **AND** "*example2.com*" points to "*/var/www/html/website2*"

Comment: Valid example websites are example.{com|net|org}, if you want to use those.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the default Apache2 available on EC2's default Amazon distro of Linux... you didn't state, so I don't know for sure. You could be using `nginx` for all I know, in which case these instructions are wasted.

You need to edit `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` or `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` (whichever one exists) and change your virtual host configuration. See [the Apache reference guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) for details. It even has some examples.

Generally, you'll need to remove or repurpose any existing `<VirtualHost ...` blocks and make sure you have something like this in your config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The above instruction is correct. I would add- keep your DocumentRoot name and ServerName same. It did not work for me until I renamed so that both matched.

Comment: For Amazon Linux, it's `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a subdomain and want to point it to the

/var/www/html/<example.website.in>

go to /etc/apache2/sites-available

then you need to make example.website.in.conf file and edit the values

You can find a default copy 000-default.conf of the configuration in the folder

Enable the site by sudo a2ensite example.website.in

more here https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-the-ubuntu-operating-system/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].